# How to fix an activation error in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, activation

I have some Windows 2008 servers I setup for development purposes, that fall under my MSDN subscription.

It's been a while, but I thought I properly activated them using the command line and the volume license keys I got through my MSDN account. However, now when I try to login I get an activation error message, but no choices on how to fix it. I click close and it logs me out.

How can I go about fixing this? I can't get a command line, so I can't see how to enter a new activation server or key, or anything. The whole volume license thing is making 2008 server a total pain.

Update:

When I click on "more information" this is what I get. Clicking on the 'you can also contact Microsoft" link just brings up a help screen.

Any idea what service it's talking about with error 0x80070426? I can remotely connect from computer management to start the service.
:

[alt text http://kevlar.net/activation_error.png](http://kevlar.net/activation_error.png)

Comment: Can you post the error? generally you should be in reduced functionality mode- not locked out alltogether.

Comment: I concur with Jim B. Also, an FYI: I've had pretty good luck, almost every time contacting MS regarding MSDN licensing, (seriously, as opposed to other issues. :) Might be a good option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but did you install while Win2008 was still in RC?

**EDIT:**

Ok, here's a [post of a similar problem](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/genuinevista/thread/14983d5e-c745-4a33-8ee8-610e5eb70271) from the MS Forums related to Vista where the error was thrown because the software licensing service had stopped.  It also mentions getting the latest SP from [KB931573](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;931573) (again, Vista related).

Comment: No, it was a regular release DVD I installed from.

Answer (score 0):

Some license types of Windows Server 2008, Vista (and I am assuming Windows 7) look for an instance of the Key Management Service (KMS) on your network. I think the error you are receiving is Win2k8 saying it cannot find this service.

This quote is from [MS's Volume Licensing page](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx):

> Volume Activation (VA) applies to
>   Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008
>   operating systems. It helps automate
>   and manage the activation process
>   while addressing the piracy and
>   product key management problems
>   associated with keys issued for
>   Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.
>
> You can use either or both VA methods
>   in your organization:
>
> > Key Management
> >     Service (KMS) uses a KMS key to
> >     activate a KMS host machine and
> >     establish a local activation service
> >     in your environment. Windows Vista and
> >     Windows Server 2008 systems connect to
> >     the KMS host for activation.
> >
> > A Multiple Activation Key (MAK) is used
> >     to activate Windows Vista and Windows
> >     Server 2008 systems directly with
> >     Microsoft's hosted activation servers.

If this is not what is wrong in your case, then a call to your MSDN rep may be needed as there may be a problem with your key.

Answer (score 0):

Just seconding the answer from Rob Allen... I recently installed a volume licensed version of server 2008 and it required getting a MAK key. In my case, I had to go to the e-open site and check my entitlement, etc.  Then I got a MAK key and a KMS key.  Since I was not setting up a KMS server, I downloaded the Volume Activation Management Tool to use with the MAK key.

It gave me, I think, 15 days before I had to get activation sorted out.
If you have a volume license issue here is a link for you:
http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx